# Fundamental Units in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ with $d \equiv 1 \mod 4$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, number-fields, continued-fractions

It is well known and often cited how the fundamental units for the number ring of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ look like. In the case of $d\equiv 2,3 \mod 4$ the number ring is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ and in case of $d\equiv 1 \mod 4$ it is $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}]$.
The fundamental unit can be written with the help of continued fraction.

As far as I was able to observe there is a similar behaviour for $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ also for $d\equiv 1 \mod 4$. There is a little difference in terms of the convergents of the continued fractions that the ones that would usually be the fundamental unit are having a norm of $-1$ (so not being really the fundamental unit.

I am considering an equivalent way of writing the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{Z}[\alpha], \text{ with } \alpha = \lfloor\sqrt{d}\rfloor+ \sqrt{d}
\end{align}

It is well-known that the continued fractions of $\alpha$ is

\begin{align}
\alpha = [\overline{a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{t-1}}],
\end{align}

i.e. $\alpha$ has purely periodic continued fractions with period $t$.

I am able to show that $p_{t-1} - q_{t-1} \alpha$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$, whereas $\frac{p_i}{q_i}$ describes the $i$th convergent of $\alpha$.

In the book "Solving the Pell Equation" by Michael J. JacobsonJr., Hugh C. Williams, they show that doing this in the cases $d\equiv 2,3 \mod 4$ is actually a fundamental unit. (In case of $d\equiv 1 \mod 4$ they use an $\alpha$ described via the adjoint element in that case in the same fashion.)

My question is now: Is the element $p_{t-1} - q_{t-1} \alpha$ a fundamental unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$?
I am somewhat sure there is some good reference for that, but was not able to find it. I would have expected to find that rather easily since it is so closely connected to $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ since $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ is a natural subring of $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}]$ to look at in the case $d\equiv 1 \mod 4$.

Comment: I don’t see a clearly expressed question here. Edit your post to be more explicit about what you are asking. Solutions to $x^2-dy^2 = \pm 1$ can be found from the continued fraction for $\sqrt{d}$ for all $d$ that are *not a perfect square* (even if $d\equiv 0 \bmod 4$). Many accounts of continued fractions or Pell’s equation will discuss this.

Comment: Hi KConrad, thank you very much. You are right, I should clear this up a bit. I hope the way I have asked it now is one that makes clear what I am looking for.

Comment: Your statement looks strange. For $d=7$ we have $p_{t-1} - q_{t-1} \alpha
=[0,15,\overline{1,14}],$ and this number is not a fundamental unit.

Comment: Dear Alexey, it is a fundamental unit. You calculate $(p_{t-1}-q_{t-1}\alpha)(p_{t-1}-q_{t-1}\overline{\alpha}) = 1$ showing that it is a unit. One then can show that is actually a fundamental unit.

Comment: @ThomasLachmann Where exactly in their book do Jacobson & Williams prove the claim that you claim they prove?

Comment: If I recall correctly, this is done in Borevich-Shafarevich, chapter 2, for any order in a quadratic number field.

Comment: @SalvoTringali In section 3.3 after Theorem 3.8. They give the solutions to the Pell Equation there in terms of convergents.

Comment: @EFinat-S Thank you! I try to have a look into this book. I think I found a proof for myself (as well for any order). Would be good if I could verify this, since I am not 100% sure yet.

Comment: I you search "borevich shafarevich" in google, the first link is the pdf from that book.